# sybase ase database is it free

Tags: linux, sap-ase

We want to use Sybase database, any of these versions:

> 12, 12.5, 12.5.1, 12.5.2, and 12.5.3

I'm not sure if Sybase ASE for Linux is free for production use without any CPU or disk limitation?

Comment: I doubt it - Sybase is a for-profit company, not open source.  What did their web site tell you?

Comment: Not really programming related, [Serverfault.com](http://serverfault.com/faq) might be better for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean with `ASE` Adaptive Server Enterprise, then only the "express" and "developer" editions are free.

More details on the Sybase website:

http://www.sybase.com/products/databasemanagement/adaptiveserverenterprise

Comment: i found this http://www.sypron.nl/get_ase_soft.html so there is no unlimited production use database